# The `ProcessDataOccurred` event of my `IProcessDataPublisher` resource is not processed

Tags: moryx

I have a resources in my application which inherit from `SomeCellBase`, which implements the `IProcessDataPublisher` interface as shown below

```cs
[ResourceRegistration]
public abstract class SomeCellBase : Cell, IProcessDataPublisher
{
    protected virtual void OnProcessDataOccured(Measurement measurement)
    {
        ProcessDataOccurred?.Invoke(this, measurement);
    }

    public event EventHandler<Measurement> ProcessDataOccurred;
}
```

I also have a reference to the Moryx.ProcessData.Adapter.ResourceManagement package in my application.

However the `ProcessDataOccurred` EventHandler is always null, as if the resource would not have been registered by the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the facade of the `ResourceManagement` you don't receive your original object, but instead a runtime generated proxy with the same public resource interfaces.

For that the `ProxyGenerator` only searches for interfaces derived from `IResource` to avoid accidently publishing access to `IDisposable` for example. Any non resources interfaces that should also be visible, must be exported using the [ResourceAvailabeAsAttribute](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Framework/blob/dev/src/Moryx.AbstractionLayer/Resources/Attributes/ResourceAvailableAsAttribute.cs)

In your case:

```cs
[ResourceRegistration, ResourceAvailableAs(typeof(IProcessDataPublisher))]
public abstract class SomeCellBase : Cell, IProcessDataPublisher
{
    protected virtual void OnProcessDataOccured(Measurement measurement)
    {
        ProcessDataOccurred?.Invoke(this, measurement);
    }

    public event EventHandler<Measurement> ProcessDataOccurred;
}
```